# yup Validation Schema Sync vs Async Validation and displaying multiple errors for one field

Tags: javascript, yup

I have two questions related to Yup validation library... Those questions are connected to each other.

First Question.

Is there any way how I can enable validation that will return all errors from validation. Look at example:

```
  const petSchema = yup.string().min( 5 ).oneOf( [ 'cat', 'dog' ] );

  petSchema.validate( 'ox', { abortEarly: false } ).catch( ( e ) => {
    console.log( e );
  } );
```

I expect that I will receive error message from `min` and `oneOf` but instead I just receiving one error: `this must be one of the following values: cat, dog`. This is silly example but I have password form with different validation rules and I want to display those rules all at one to the user. I think I can find other use cases for it... I think `abortEarly` should work but it just not works as expected.

Second question:

Let's assume I have `email` field and I want to check it on frontend side with `string().required().email()` schema and one more check in backend using async custom `test` method.

Problem is that when `required` or `email` fails my async `test` is also called. Is there any way how I can stop calling async `test` if previous sync validators fails? Also this is related to first question because it does not make any sense if I can only display one error and it generates not required traffic on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: About your validation, it seems to me that simply `oneOf` and `min` are not compatible, and it make sense to me (if you're checking an enum, why should you check the length?). Testing with `min` and `max` you get correctly **two** ValidationError from `err.inner`, as you can see in this [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/yup-so)

About the multiple fields validation, in this case there is still a message, but if you `console.log` the error object you'll see an `errors` property, which is an array with all the detailed errors.

About the sequential validation, unfortunately this is still not supported as tracked on project issue: https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/851

Comment: Thanks for Your input but `errors` property from error object contains just one error - always.

Comment: I didn't get the question right, updated the answer.

Comment: So it seems that `oneOf` is not compatible with min. I wonder if this is documented somewhere? Why oneOf override all other error messages? Thanks anyway for this example! Indeed it works but why it not work with `oneOf`? Any other validator that are not compatible for multi errors?

Comment: Can’t find any docs about it, but I think it is strictly related to oneOf way of working: since it is whitelisting values, other checks becomes useless

Comment: Thank You for help :)

Comment: Apparently validate takes in two parameters. The object to validate and {abortEarly: false}. Add the `abortEarly` param set to false in order to return all errors. 
Found here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62041081/7427437